# How to batch process csv files into existing xlsx file to append its data?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've found a post which takes csv files and writes them to an excel file.  Its good because Ive actually already generated my csv files for this analysis.  But in the future I would like to skip that part and go straight to writing my resulting forecast data to an excel file by appending it.

What function could I use to take a forecast data set like this and append it to a specific cell of an existing xlsx file?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
import warnings
from openpyxl import load_workbook

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#NOTE:start for loop with i & specify column to open, PROCESSSTUFF, 

df=pd.read_excel('testdata2.xlsx')
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df=df.set_index('Date')
df.head()

#NOTE:df.iloc[:,0:a]
df=df.iloc[:,[2]]
print(df)
filename=df.columns[0]
print(filename)

#PROCESSSTUFF: 80% train and 20% test. Currently we have '15=6,'16-'19x12=4x12=48+6=54 so 80%~42TRAIN
#take from the start to -12 months is train, from -12 to end is test
train, test = df[:-12], df[-12:]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train)
train=scaler.transform(train)
test=scaler.transform(test)
n_input=12
n_features=1

generator=TimeseriesGenerator(train,train,length=n_input,batch_size=6)

model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200,activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=140)

pred_list=[]

batch=train[-n_input:].reshape((1,n_input,n_features))

for i in range(n_input):
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0])
    batch=np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)
df_predict=pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(pred_list),index=df[-n_input:].index, columns=['Prediccion'])

df_test=pd.concat([df,df_predict],axis=1)

#Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
plt.plot(df_test.index, df_test[filename])
plt.plot(df_test.index, df_test['Prediccion'],color='r')

####
train = df

scaler.fit(train)
train=scaler.transform(train)
n_input=12
n_features=1

generator=TimeseriesGenerator(train,train,length=n_input,batch_size=6)

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=140)

pred_list=[]

batch=train[-n_input:].reshape((1,n_input,n_features))

for i in range(n_input):
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0])
    batch=np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)

from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
add_dates=[df.index[-1] + DateOffset(months=x) for x in range(0,13)]
future_dates=pd.DataFrame(index=add_dates[1:],columns=df.columns)

df_predict=pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(pred_list),
                        index=future_dates[-n_input:].index, columns=['Prediccion'])

df_proj=pd.concat([df,df_predict],axis=1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.plot(df_proj.index, df_proj[filename])
plt.plot(df_proj.index, df_proj['Prediccion'],color='r')
plt.legend(loc='best',fontsize='large')
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.show()

df_proj.tail(14)
#b57
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(df, engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook(df)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)
df_predict.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=7,startrow=6) ## here you can specify your cell

writer.save()
#b57
df_proj.tail(14).to_csv(str(filename) + '.csv',index=False)
```

lines between the #b57 comments is where I inserted the suggested code and got lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn = r'VentasAceroHistoricas2.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(fn)
df_predict=pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(pred_list),
                        index=future_dates[-n_input:].index, columns=['Prediccion'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook(fn)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)
df_predict.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=7,startrow=6) ## here you can specify your cell

writer.save()
```

Comment: ok my complete code already uses a df and a df_predict object.  So I got confused when you started callingcdf and df_predict.  I updated my post with the complete code.